# Javascript button which submits Contact Form 7 form, then redirects to URL

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make a 'Choose Your E-mail Plan' page on my website - https://godesignweb.co.uk/e-mail-services/monthly-email/ & I'm having trouble submitting the form, and then redirecting to a specific paypal page depending on what package they've chosen.

As you can see from the website it's almost there, and depending on which package you choose, it displays a different  at the bottom of the page.(which I want to contain a submit button which redirects the user).

I currently have

```
<input type="submit" form="email" value="send">
```

which is outside of the contact form 7 form, and works (it's on the Pro plan) if you click it, it submits the form.

Is there anyway I can call 3 different functions for the 3 buttons which;

1) submit the form (including checking the validation that it normally does_
2) redirect the user to a paypal page

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

As taken from your comment to my answer, here's what you could try if you use three different submit buttons:

1.) assign each SUBMIT button a unique name:

```
<!-- button in starter form -->
<input type="submit" name="submit-starter" form="email" value="Send"/>

<!-- button in pro form -->
<input type="submit" name="submit-pro" form="email" value="Send"/>

<!-- button in advanced form -->
<input type="submit" name="submit-advanced" form="email" value="Send"/>
```

2.) On PHP side:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-starter'])) {
  $plan= 'starter';
  $priceMonthly= 3.99;
} elseif (isset($_POST['submit-pro'])) {
  $plan= 'pro';
  $priceMonthly= 5.99;
} elseif (isset($_POST['submit-advanced'])) {
  $plan= 'advanced';
  $priceMonthly= 7.99;
}

// create the Paypal form
?>
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php print $plan; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php print $price; ?>">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pay with PayPal">
</form>
```

**-- previous answer --**

I am not sure if I got you right because I somehow just see one (submit) button instead of three buttons so I hope my answer is not misleading or doesn't make sense in your scenario:

I assume that:

1. the three buttons refer to the three plans you offer
2. you only want to have one validation function
3. based on the plan selection you want to have different prices on the Paypal checkout form

The below code will only deal with the frontend control, you should definitely add a second server-based verification to make sure nobody injected/manipulated your frontend form code.

Instead of using a standard submit button, change it to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="formInspectAndSubmit()" value="send"/>
```

and add a form variable for your plan

```
<input type="hidden" id="input-plan" name="input-plan"/>
```

Your `FRONTEND validation` function should look like this:

```
function formInspectAndSubmit() {
  // validation stuff ...

  // retrieve the chosen plan
  var plan= $('.active').prop('id');

  switch (plan) {
    case 'starter':
      // set hidden parameters for starters
      $('#input-plan').val('starter');
      break;
    case 'pro':
      // set hidden parameters for pro
      break;
    case 'advanced':
      // set hidden parameters for starters
      break;
  }
  // set POST variables based on above plan and redirect to validation page; this should then forward to Paypal checkout page with price defined by chosen plan
  $('#email').submit();
}
```

Comment: I think this is over complicating it, if you click on the 3 different plans on the top it shows a different div at the bottom, this div just needs a different submit button which submits the form, then redirects to a different URL

Comment: I've just viewed your updated answer and It's not exactly what I'm after.

Can you go on my website now, i'm on the live chat I'll talk to you there

Comment: Plus, it needs to submit the form first, then redirect depending on what submit button is pressed

Comment: @AdamBoustead could you close your question so that it won't become one of those zombie questions here on SO? Thanks